# jquery mobile- swipe for the same page with different content

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

i am trying to swipe for the same page with different content and with the slide animation.
i am using jquery mobile. however, after the page transition witout a slide animation.
What am i missing?

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#MatchStats", function() {

 $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#MatchStats", function( e ) {
   if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {      
        $.mobile.changePage(  '#MatchStats', { transition: "slide",allowSamePageTransition: true });
       getMatchStats(indexMathces,GroupID);          
    }           
   else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
          $.mobile.changePage( '#MatchStats' , {
                    transition: "slide",
                    allowSamePageTransition: true,
                    reverse: true});
            getMatchStats(indexMathces,GroupID);              
        }    
 });
});
```

Comment: Remove this `$.mobile.changePage.defaults.allowSamePageTransition = true;` as it works only if placed before loading jQM. So add it before or after `transition` this way `allowSamePageTransition: true`. The

Comment: i did not understand you, can you please show me an example?

Comment: check the code here http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/RZP5z/